# Rails Building a Admin Console for Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First of all i have followed the Agile Web Development with Rails Third Edition Book. However i would like to be able to create a admin part of the application. There is one to a degree and as i have the following:

Controller Admin

Login, Logout, Index

Controller Products

I would like to create a section in the Admin Controller to control the products.
I have tried looking around on the net and playing around on the system. But i am getting a confused on the issue.

I tried creating a Products pages in the in the Admin/Views folder. This allows me to View the products at the following: //localhost/admin/products. This is great but if i want to edit and create products i would like //localhost/admin/products/:id/edit etc. and edit and etc can only happen within the admin URl.

working with Rails 2.0.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You really want to be using a later version of Rails than 2.0.2 if you are able to - 2.3.14 is latest in the v2 and v3.1.0 actually came out not very long ago.

To answer your question you want to be looking into route namespacing which allow you to group routes/resources together inside a namespace, eg admin.

```
namespace :admin do
  root :to => 'admin#index' #Default route for when you got to /admin
  resources :products
```

This last route will create all 7 restful routes for your products model inside the /admin namespace. You will want a controller named app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb where you will have the index, create, update...etc methods and corresponding views in app/views/admin/views/productions

Comment: Thank John I thought this might be the case. However is there not an idea for doing this at deployment level. Meaning App1 is the Website and App2 for Admin place the App2 on www.domain.com/admin can this be done?

Comment: It could be done but I prefer to keep it all in one application and in the same repo. You'd end up sharing a lot of code between apps at the model layer and unless there really is a need to consider it then I'd keep it all in one application - especially if you're new to rails. I've not created seperate apps in the 3 years I've been doing Rails dev.

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer you're happy with as the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespace for this. In your routes.rb:

```
map.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
admin.resources :products
end
```

and then, generate admin/products controller and use with REST:

```
script/generate controller admin/products


admin_products_path
edit_admin_products_path(product.id)
```